# what is wordpress login process with third party authentication provider

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-login

How wordpress authenticate with third party such as facebook?

i know wordpress will generate cookies to web browsers and web browsers send request with cookies, then wordpress knows the user has logged in.

I also know how to get user information through facebook api. Which url or method should i make in order to make wordpress generates cookies?

Comment: To make that you can use plugin like : Social login.

Comment: @HelpingHands yes, i know there are social login plugins, but i would like to how the process then i know how to develop apps to login to wordpress with third parties.

Comment: That will require to do lot of research and development.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option by creating hooks to the authenticate function in the pluggable.php.

Hope [this slide](http://www.slideshare.net/technosailor/wordpress-third-party-authentication) would help you move in the right direction.